# Jquery Toggle Menu / Show and Hide function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am using a Jquery Toggle sidebar menu, so there is a down arrow in the menu to push the menu down to show sub-menu(s) every time you click on it. My problem is when there is no child menu/sub-menu, the down arrow is still showing up, and when you click on it, it eats the same level menu below. I am using the menu in Silverstripe. How can I make the arrow shows only when there is a child menu/submenu?

/*-----------------------------------------------Here is my toggle menu js--------------------------------------------------*/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.second_level').hide();

$("div.menu > h3").css("background", "url(themes/tutorial/images/menuarrowdown.gif) no-repeat right");

$('div.menu > h3').click(function() {

$(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function() {

//set arrow depending on whether menu is shown or hidden
if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {

$(this).prev().css("background", "url(themes/tutorial/images/menuarrowdown.gif) no-repeat right");
} else {
$(this).prev().css("background", "url(themes/tutorial/images/menuarrowup.gif) no-repeat right");
}
return false;
});
});
});
```

/*------------------------------------Here is my html code----------------------------------------------*/

```
<div id="productmenu"> <!-- productmenu starts -->
<div class="menu">                      
  <h3><a href="#">Category 1</a></h3>
    <ul class="second_level">
      <li><a href="page.html">Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page.html">Option 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div> <!-- /menu -->

<div class="menu">

   <h3><a href="#">Category 2</a></h3>

</div> <!-- /menu -->

<div class="menu">
  <h3><a href="#">Category 3</a></h3>
     <ul class="second_level">
      <li><a href="page.html">Option 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="page.html">Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page.html">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- /menu -->
</div><!-- /productmenu -->
```

/*------------------------------------Here is my page.ss----------------------------------------------*/

```
  <% control Menu(2) %>

     <h3><a href="$Link" title="Go to the &quot;{$Title}&quot; page">$MenuTitle</a></h3>

        <% if Children %>   <ul class="second_level">
              <% control Children %>
               <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="Go to the &quot;{$Title}&quot; page">$MenuTitle</a></li>
              <% end_control %></ul>

        <% end_if %>
  <% end_control %>
```

Your help is appreciated. Please see example pic below.

Thanks
Sam

[image]

**Edit: To fix the eating up menu issue, just move <% control Menu(2) %> above  and <% end_control %> below the finish div of menu. Js solution is to use Matt's new Js. Thanks Matt, Iank and Milo! I appreciate your help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never tell your system to not print the down arrow if no child exists. It adds the arrow to every H3 that exists in them menu and never considers if it has children or not. So we need to check each menu item to see if it has children. The following should do that:

```
$("div.menu").each(function(){

  if($(this).children().length > 1) // See if the H3 is the only child
  {
      $(this).children("H3").css("background", "url(themes/tutorial/images/menuarrowdown.gif) no-repeat right");
  }

});
```

**Presently I'm on lunch break and do not have time to fully test this. I have no verified this will work.**

EDIT: Modified code after Sam put in his pure HTML.

EDIT2: After Sam supplied a fiddle, I forked it and made corrections.Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GvGoldmedal/Wp2em/

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks very much for your response. This line came up an error $("div.menu > h3").each(funtion(){... and it's still not working. I've supplied my html code as well above. Any other suggestions? I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Sam, I updated the code after looking at your pure HTML. I apologize again that I cannot effectively test my suggestions since I'm on limited time. If this issue hasn't been resolved by tonight I'll recreate it on my local and figure out what is wrong. Cheers. :)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks, I the first line is still showing error and its not still not working. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/uuGxe/2/ if you have time later on. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply, it's working with my first issue which is showing/hiding arrow when there is/isn't submenu(s). When I implemented it to Silverstripe, the none arrow h3 menu eg category 2 is closing the next menu in this case category 3, any ideas on why that is? Could it be someone to do with the click function in js? Thanks very much for your help. :)

Comment: I just figured out why the menu got eaten up in Silverstripe. I need to move <% control Menu(2) %> up one div. Thanks for your great js fix. The menu is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the templating language you are using to create your menu, but I might be able to help with jQuery. It would be a lot of help if you could provide the final generated html of your menu.

I assume that your div elements are a menu item, your h3 elements a menu item content, and your ul is a submenu. If this is correct, you could hide the arrows by adding the following line to your main function:

```
$('div.menu:has(ul.second_level) > h3').css('background', '');
```

If you find this code to be too slow, you could identify the menus without submenus on the server side and give them a class, something like menu_no_submenu, so you could then replace the complex selector in the above code with much faster '.menu_no_submenu' or, even better, do the whole arrow hiding thing in css.

Comment: Hi Milo Rasic, I have put my html code above now. It's still not working. Any other suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the background in the template code rather than using jQuery.

Make a css class that contains the background.

```
.menuHeader { background: url("themes/tutorial/images/menuarrowdown.gif") no-repeat scroll right center transparent; }
```

Then in your template code set the class to the h3 if the menu has children.

```
<% control Menu(2) %>
    <% if Children %>   
      <h3 class="menuHeader"><a href="$Link" title="Go to the &quot;{$Title}&quot; page">$MenuTitle</a></h3>
    <ul class="second_level">
          <% control Children %>
            <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="Go to the &quot;{$Title}&quot; page">$MenuTitle</a></li>
          <% end_control %>
    </ul>
   <% else %>
        <h3><a href="$Link" title="Go to the &quot;{$Title}&quot; page">$MenuTitle</a></h3>
   <% end_if %><% end_control %>
```

Comment: Hi Ianks, thanks for your reply. I can see what you are trying to do, but the arrow disappeared entirely unless you click on it, and every time when I click on h3 which hasn't got sub menu, it still eats the menu underneath. Not sure why? Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: It is probably because you have $(this).next().slideToggle which means that it will toggle the next element no matter what it is? Use an if inside your $('div.menu > h3').click to check that there is a <ul class="second_level"> before you do the slidetoggle.

Comment: EDIT: I pasted the jquery into jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to eat the menu underneath. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/DpPTZ/ it seems to work ok.

Comment: Hi Ianks, sorry i'm new to this, how do i out an if statement for the click function? Thanks heaps.

Comment: I know it all looks good when it is in html and js but when i implement it to Silverstripe, the menu underneath got taken by the menu above (they are same level). I think your suggestion on the if statement may help it, but im not sure how to do it. Any suggestions? Thank you Iank.

Comment: Hi Sam. Silverstripe shouldn't affect it if the html is the same. I would suggest that you open up a new question asking about this problem as it seems different from your original question? Then if possible it would be good if you could put a live page up of your Silverstripe website that people can use?

Comment: I've tried it on jsfiddle as well and it works correctly. I too think that there is little chance that Silverstripe can interfere with how html, css and js work. Sam, when there is weird behaviour like this, you should always check whether the changes you make to the code are taken into account. Open the source of your page and check if correct html is generated and whether the correct version of js and css files are being loaded.

Comment: Thanks Ianks, and thanks Milo Rasic. This is definitely a group effect. I used Matt's Js code and followed up with all you guys' comments, it turns out i need to move the <% control Menu(2) %> up one div to fix the eatting up menus issue, silly me. Hey thanks very much for your help, you guys are great, I really appreciate your help and follow up. :)